# After homebrew installation and using it to install miniconda on Monterey MacOS, conda is not found.(Q1) How to resolve? (Q2) How to remove miniconda?

Tags: homebrew, miniconda, macos-monterey

Using: MacOS Monterey v12.2, Apple M1 Pro chip.

After installation of homebrew and using it to install miniconda with this command 'brew install --cask miniconda' on the mac terminal, it states that conda is not found.

Yet, if i key the command 'brew list' on mac terminal, miniconda is seen in the casks.

(Q1) How to resolve the above i.e. make miniconda work via this homebrew download method? (Also, it seems like unlike in intel MacOS, miniconda is stored in this directory -> "opt/homebrew/Caskroom/miniconda/base" in M1 MacOS)

(Q2) Alternatively, i downloaded the miniconda installer (from https://docs.conda.io/en/latest/miniconda.html). This miniconda installer works and it seems to reside in a different path -> "/Users/xxxx/opt/miniconda3" (refer to Image 1). Concern that there might be conflict if there are two miniconda in my macOS. So then, how can i remove the miniconda which i downloaded earlier via homebrew? The command 'brew uninstall miniconda' or ''brew uninstall --cask miniconda' did not work? (refer to Image 2)

[image]

[image]

Answer (score -1):

I kept running into these kinds of problems with python on my M1 Mac until I went completely to Rosetta on the command line wrt python. For that, I did the following:

1. Update Rosetta:
   In a Terminal type:

```bash
softwareupdate --install-rosetta
```

2. In Finder, type <kbd>⇧</kbd><kbd>⌘</kbd><kbd>G</kbd> and go to /Applications/Utilities. Then duplicate Terminal:

[image]

3. Rename the second Terminal to "Rosetta" (or whatever you like) and have it execute in Rosetta by checking "Open using Rosetta" in the "Get Info" dialogue:

[image]

4. Open a Rosetta Terminal and make sure it shows `i386` when you issue the command `arch`:

[image]

4. In that terminal, install homebrew (per the homebrew homepage):

```bash
/bin/bash -c "$(curl -fsSL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Homebrew/install/HEAD/install.sh)"
```

5. Once homebrew has been installed, install miniconda using homebrew:

```bash
brew install --cask miniconda
```

6. Create a conda environment, for instance here a python 3.9 env named `py39`:

```bash
conda create -n py39 python=3.9
```

7. Activate the environment:

```bash
conda activate py39
```

From here on out, you have a fully functioning i386 Python system. This has resolved all problems that I had with Numpy, Pandas, Azure, etc. on my M1 Mac.

Answer (score -1):

(Q1) I installed `miniconda3` without having to resort to `brew` as follows:

```
mkdir -p ~/miniconda3
curl https://repo.anaconda.com/miniconda/Miniconda3-latest-MacOSX-arm64.sh -o ~/miniconda3/miniconda.sh
bash ~/miniconda3/miniconda.sh -b -u -p ~/miniconda3
rm -rf ~/miniconda3/miniconda.sh
```

Then initialise your shell using:

```
~/miniconda3/bin/conda init bash
~/miniconda3/bin/conda init zsh
```

(Q2)
You could try `brew cask uninstall --force --cask miniconda` to force the removal of the Cask.